# How do we generate the creation dates of all users added in dynamics 365 crm?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

1. How do we generate the creation dates of all users added in dynamics 365 crm?
2. How do we generate the audit trail of dynamics crm?

Comment: It’s too broad and off topic here. You can search internet for similar topics and start somewhere before posting particular problem you’re facing

Comment: 1. Users get created the moment they're assigned a license
2. Enable auditing for your entity